# Does Automaton scripting have a focus function?

Tags: java, groovy, automation, ui-automation

Does anyone know if Automaton has a focus function?  I have a tabbed panel and I'm simply attempting to switch tabs.  My goal is to automate this with the groovy script option rather than integrating it into the java source code.  Currently I am using the format:

```
clickOn 'name:jPanel1'
```

unfortunately that isn't working.  I tried using the text option as well with no luck. This is the tool I'm using: [Automaton](https://github.com/renatoathaydes/Automaton)

Comment: Usually click on element makes it "active" or say in focus. If it's not working - the click itself may be made on the wrong element or non-clickable area of an element. Try changing element to click

Comment: ok...so click 'name:jPanel1' vs. clickOn 'name:jPanel1'....I'll give it a shot thanks.

Comment: Well I changed elements, renamed everything and still no results.  I see that it my cursor position (to where it would be on the next panel) and it attempt to manipulate the first panel.  So it tries to perform the right task but seems to get confused on which panel is the top element.